# I do not understand why after clicking the link "undefined" is shown instead of the passed argument

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why after clicking the link "undefined" is shown. Does anyone know why?

```js
let allBlocks = ["one","two"];

for (i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<p id="" onclick="test(allBlocks[i])">Link</p>';
}

function test(n){
    alert(n);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your code in the click handler is

```
test(allBlocks[i])
```

It would appear your code is at global scope, which is the only reason it's not throwing an error. When the click occurs, `i` has the value `allBlocks.length`, which is beyond the end of the array. Accessing an array entry that isn't there results in `undefined`.

The minimum change is to use string concatenation to put the value of `i` in the click handler rather than `i`:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<p id="" onclick="test(allBlocks[' + i + '])">Link</p>';
```

However, rather than doing that, I'd suggest modern event handling via `addEventListener`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
//   ^^^---- Note
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = "Link";
  p.addEventListener("click", test.bind(null, allBlocks[i]));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

---

Side note: `element.innerHTML += ...` is never a good idea. It forces the browser to loop through the entire contents of `element`, building up an HTML string for the DOM structure it contains, and then pass that string to the JavaScript layer; then the JavaScript layer has to add to the string and pass it back to the browser; then the browser has to parse the HTML, creating a bunch of new, replacement elements, wipe out the contents of `element`, and replace it with those new elements. Other than being a lot of unnecessary work, it also destroys any event handlers on the elements, any state information, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Even `i` is in global scope after the loop value of `i` would be array length so it would be like `array[array.length]` which will be `undefined`. To make it work append the value of `i` at that point along with string.

```js
let allBlocks = ["one", "two"];

for (i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {

  document.body.innerHTML += `<p id="" onclick="test(allBlocks[${i}])">Link</p>`;

}

function test(n) {
  alert(n);
}
```

---

Or in case the array is not in global scope then you have to append the value itself as a string argument(wrap with quotes).

```js
let allBlocks = ["one", "two"];

for (i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {

  document.body.innerHTML += `<p id="" onclick="test('${allBlocks[i]}')">Link</p>`;

}

function test(n) {
  alert(n);
}
```

---

***FYI :*** `document.body.innerHTML +=...` is a really bad idea since it will always recreate DOM elements which will remove any attached event handler, properties,etc... So always keep a variable within the loop to keep the HTML string and then update content finally(in your case).

Comment: now it works! I thought that the problem is with scope but Im still learning :) Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is string interpolation

```
for (i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {

  document.body.innerHTML += `<p id="" onclick="test(${allBlocks[i]})">Link</p>`;

}

function test(n){
    alert(n);
}
```

This will pass the value of `allblocks[i]` instead of just a string

Answer (score 1):

`i` is acting as a global variable. Also you can use template literals

```js
let allBlocks = ["one", "two"];

for (let i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<p id="" onclick="test(allBlocks[${i}])">Link</p>`;
}

function test(n) {
  alert(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

..because `allBlocks[i]` is undefined. You need the value of `i` to be rendered in your HTML.

```js
let allBlocks = ["one","two"];

for (i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {

  document.body.innerHTML += '<p id="" onclick="test(allBlocks['+i+'])">Link</p>';

}

function test(n){
    alert(n);
}
```